# How to prevent Docker build from creating new steps?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am trying to build my Dockerfile, and each time I try it adds an identical 14 steps. I now have 154 steps, and am deeply frustrated. How can I delete these steps, and prevent them from re-occuring?

My command that I'm running:

```sh
sudo docker build - < Dockerfile --tag detect-wpi

docker run --name edgetpu-wpi \
--rm -it --privileged -p 6006:6006 \
--mount type=bind,src=${DETECT_DIR},dst=/tensorflow/models/research/learn \
detect-wpi
```

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM tensorflow/tensorflow:1.12.0-rc2-devel

RUN git clone https://github.com/tensorflow/models.git && \
    mv models /tensorflow/models

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y python python-tk
RUN pip install Cython && \
    pip install contextlib2 && \
    pip install pillow && \
    pip install lxml && \
    pip install jupyter && \
    pip install matplotlib

# Get protoc 3.0.0, rather than the old version already in the container
RUN curl -OL "https://github.com/google/protobuf/releases/download/v3.0.0/protoc-3.0.0-linux-x86_64.zip" && \
    unzip protoc-3.0.0-linux-x86_64.zip -d proto3 && \
    mv proto3/bin/* /usr/local/bin && \
    mv proto3/include/* /usr/local/include && \
    rm -rf proto3 protoc-3.0.0-linux-x86_64.zip

# Install pycocoapi
RUN git clone --depth 1 https://github.com/cocodataset/cocoapi.git && \
    cd cocoapi/PythonAPI && \
    make -j8 && \
    cp -r pycocotools /tensorflow/models/research && \
    cd ../../ && \
    rm -rf cocoapi

# Run protoc on the object detection repo
RUN cd /tensorflow/models/research && \
    protoc object_detection/protos/*.proto --python_out=.

# Set the PYTHONPATH to finish installing the API
ENV PYTHONPATH $PYTHONPATH:/tensorflow/models/research:/tensorflow/models/research/slim

# Install wget (to make life easier below) and editors (to allow people to edit
# the files inside the container)
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y wget vim emacs nano

ARG work_dir=/tensorflow/models/research
# Get object detection transfer learning scripts.
ARG scripts_link="http://storage.googleapis.com/cloud-iot-edge-pretrained-models/docker/obj_det_scripts.tgz"
RUN cd ${work_dir} && \
    wget -O obj_det_scripts.tgz ${scripts_link} && \
    tar zxvf obj_det_scripts.tgz

RUN cd /tensorflow/models/research && \
    git clone NEW_LINK && \
    cd FRCCoralTFLite && \
    cp setup.sh ../setup.sh

WORKDIR ${work_dir}
```

Comment: Will try to repro. What's `NEW_LINK`?

Comment: Excluding step #13, it (re)builds successfully for me, caching steps and does not rebuild layers. When you write "I now have 154 steps", do you mean that each time you run `docker build` another 14 steps is added to the build?

Comment: NEW_LINK is a github repo url that is replaced by a script.

Comment: Yes DazWilkin, another 14 steps are added. I found that if I rm-rf $DETECT_DIR it goes bacl to 14. Thoughts?

Comment: Ah, does this explain why you're piping `Dockerfile` into `docker build`. Could that be the problem? Could you try perhaps `sed`'ing the replacement and then `docker build --file=/path/to/Dockerfile .` so that the `Dockerfile` is static for `docker build` and see whether that makes a difference?

Comment: Sorry, I'm still new to this Docker stuff. I ran `sudo docker build --file= $DETECT_DIR/Dockerfile --tag detect-wpi --no-cache
`
`docker run --name edgetpu-wpi \
--rm -it --privileged -p 6006:6006 \
--mount type=bind,src=${DETECT_DIR},dst=/tensorflow/models/research/learn \
detect-wpi
` and I got the following error: ```unable to prepare context: context must be a directory``` Apologies for formatting.

Comment: Also note: I am mostly following this guide: [https://coral.withgoogle.com/docs/edgetpu/retrain-detection/](https://coral.withgoogle.com/docs/edgetpu/retrain-detection/). You'll notice the nearly identical scripts.

Comment: Going to walk my dog. If I have time later, I'll check in on this. "context" relates to referencing files *outside* of the "current" (not quite) directory. When you run `docker build --file=some/Dockerfile .`, the period (`.`) marks the context. The build process is not permitted to reference files outside of the tree rooted on `.`. The Dockerfile itself *may* be outside of that location.

Comment: Ah, i forgot the dot. Didn't see it.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I followed the tutorial and it works for me. Were you able to get everything working?

Comment: Tutorial works for me fine too, just when i,build multiple times it makes more steps, adding time to my build.

Comment: I found that if i remove DETECT_DIR it works but that doesn't seem optimal

Comment: `DETECT_DIR` is just a way for the tutorial's authors to pin you to a specific directory on your host machine. After installing `Dockerfile` into that directory, the directory is then mounted into the container when it's run using the `--mount`. Your local `DETECT_DIR` then becomes the container's `/tensorflow/models/research/learn_pet` directory. If, while running the containing, you `ls -l learn_pet`, you should see your `Dockerfile` enumerated. All that said, this shouldn't be a problem and you should not suffer from repeatedly rebuilding the image.

Comment: This is one of the simplest Dockerfiles I can conjure: `FROM busybox
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/busybox","ls","-l"]`. What happens if you build that repeatedly? `docker build --tag=busyboxls --file=./Dockerfile .`

Comment: It's getting late here, I'll try that tommorow. Thanks so much.

Comment: I'm going to be offline for a few days. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

My issue was solved by clearing the docker cache.

```
docker system prune
```